# First integral of a vectorial field

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I have a problem that says:

---

Let

$$\dot x = f(x,y) $$
$$\dot y = g(x,y) $$

be a 2-dimensional ODE with vector field $X:U\to \mathbb{R}^2 $, $X=(f,g)\in \mathcal C^1 (U)$, and $U$ an open star domain of $\mathbb{R}^2 $. X is integrable if there exists a $\mathcal C^1 $ function $H: U\to \mathbb R$ which is not constant over an open set, but it is constant over the solutions of the ODE.

1. Prove that $X$ is integrable if, and only if, there exists a $\mathcal C^1 $ function $H$ such that

$$DH(x,y)X(x,y)=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} (x,y) f(x,y)+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} (x,y) g(x,y)=0 $$

---

If $\varphi(t)$ is a solution of the ODE, then $\dot \varphi = (f(\varphi),g(\varphi)) =X(\varphi)$, so if $X$ is integrable there exists a function $H$ such that $DH(\varphi)X(\varphi)=0$. Also, $DH(\varphi)X(x,y)=0, \; \forall x,y \in U$, but I don't know how to prove it in general. Maybe I should use that $U$ is a star domain, but I'm not sure because the problem has more sections.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Note that since $X$ is in $\mathcal{C}^1(U)$ an existence and uniqueness theorem works and it is guaranteed that there exists a solution to IVP $\varphi(0) = (x_0, y_0)$. Hence you can do a simple substitution in $DH(\varphi(t)) X(\varphi(t)) \equiv 0$.

Comment: Also, "only if" part of the question can be proven by plugging solution $\phi(t)$ into $H$ and taking a derivative w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: ¡Thansk Evgeny!
Very clear, I've understood it. 
For the "only if" part, if we suppose that $DH(x,y)X(x,y)\equiv 0 $, then
$\frac{d}{dt}H(\varphi(t))= DH(\varphi(t))X(\varphi(t))=0 $, so $H$ is constant over a solution $\varphi$. But I'm not sure why $H$ is not constant (over an open set). Or is this just a hypothesis?

Comment: You pick a local solution with initial values $φ(0)=(x,y)$ so that at $t=0$ you get then $DH(x,y)X(x,y)=0$.

Comment: @Relativo I think that since this is a short piece of text, $H$ has all the same properties as it was mentioned before. So, the statement should be read: "Vector field $X$ has a first integral $H$ if this locally non-constant function is constant along solutions. Such function $H$ is also a first integral $\iff$ $DH(X) \equiv 0$."